# Javascript Function Not Working In Chrome?

Tags: javascript

I have this simple code to load an image array and increment through it using an img src in a div. It works fine in Firefox but Chrome and IE11 aren't working. I've tested javascript using an alert and it's working in both browsers. What am I missing? Thanks!

```
  var counter = -1;  
  var imgArray = new Array(); 

  imgArray[0] = new Image();
  imgArray[0].src = "../Images/NewLogo1.jpg";

  imgArray[1] = new Image();
  imgArray[1].src = "../Images/NewLogo2.jpg";  

function nextImage(){
  //increments the counter and shows the next image
  counter++;
  if (counter > 1){
  counter = 0;
  } // end if  
  document.fadeImg.src = imgArray[counter].src; 
} // end nextImage

setInterval(function() {
 nextImage();
 },5000);

onload = nextImage;
```

HTML

```
<div class="homecontent" id="homecontent">
<img id="fadeImg" src="holder.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: No error in the chrome console?

Comment: describe not working?

Comment: Nothing loads in the div. I get no images at all.

Comment: <img id="fadeImg" src="holder.jpg" alt="" />

Comment: Change `document.fadeImg.src` to `document.getElementById('fadeImg').src`

Comment: THANKS j08691 that was it.

Comment: Thanks Romain Braun the Chrome Console will be a great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use **id** attribute (e.g. `<img id="fadeImg"... />`) in your HTML, then you can select it using this syntax: `document.getElementById("fadeImg").src`.

However, if you use **name** attribute (e.g. `<img name="fadeImg"... />`) in your HTML, then you can select it using the following syntax: `document.fadeImg.src`.